# Tomcat doesn't proceed after INFOS: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext after migration to Spring 3.2.3.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm migrating my application to Spring 3.2.3.RELEASE and tomcat just hang without throwing any exceptions

```
Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.
```

And here is what is displayed in my console

```
[2017-03-20 12:17:32,557] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader [main] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
[2017-03-20 12:17:32,638] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext [main] Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Mar 20 12:17:32 WET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
[2017-03-20 12:17:32,686] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader [main] Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/STG/Desktop/woork/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/perWeb/WEB-INF/lib/perDao-2.0.jar!/applicationContext-hibernate.xml]
[2017-03-20 12:17:32,820] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader [main] Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/STG/Desktop/woork/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/perWeb/WEB-INF/lib/perDao-2.0.jar!/applicationContext-datasource.xml]
[2017-03-20 12:17:32,845] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader [main] Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/STG/Desktop/woork/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/perWeb/WEB-INF/lib/perDao-2.0.jar!/applicationContext-daos.xml]
[2017-03-20 12:17:32,884] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader [main] Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/STG/Desktop/woork/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/perWeb/WEB-INF/lib/perDao-2.0.jar!/applicationContext-cache.xml]
[2017-03-20 12:17:33,035] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader [main] Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/STG/Desktop/woork/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/perWeb/WEB-INF/lib/perService-2.0.jar!/applicationContext-service.xml]
[2017-03-20 12:17:33,087] INFO  org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner [main] JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
[2017-03-20 12:17:33,349] INFO  org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner [main] JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
[2017-03-20 12:17:33,396] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader [main] Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/STG/Desktop/woork/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/perWeb/WEB-INF/lib/perService-2.0.jar!/applicationContext-scheduling.xml]
[2017-03-20 12:17:33,421] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader [main] Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/STG/Desktop/woork/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/perWeb/WEB-INF/lib/perService-2.0.jar!/applicationContext-simple-service.xml]
[2017-03-20 12:17:33,480] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory [main] Overriding bean definition for bean 'agenceService': replacing [Generic bean: class [ma.mamda.per.service.partenaire.AgenceService]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/STG/Desktop/woork/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/perWeb/WEB-INF/lib/perService-2.0.jar!/ma/mamda/per/service/partenaire/AgenceService.class]] with [Generic bean: class [ma.mamda.per.service.partenaire.AgenceService]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/STG/Desktop/woork/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/perWeb/WEB-INF/lib/perService-2.0.jar!/applicationContext-simple-service.xml]]
[2017-03-20 12:17:33,482] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory [main] Overriding bean definition for bean 'avenantService': replacing [Generic bean: class [ma.mamda.per.service.avenant.AvenantService]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/STG/Desktop/woork/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/perWeb/WEB-INF/lib/perService-2.0.jar!/ma/mamda/per/service/avenant/AvenantService.class]] with [Generic bean: class [ma.mamda.per.service.avenant.AvenantService]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/STG/Desktop/woork/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/perWeb/WEB-INF/lib/perService-2.0.jar!/applicationContext-simple-service.xml]]
[2017-03-20 12:17:33,523] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader [main] Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/STG/Desktop/woork/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/perWeb/WEB-INF/lib/perService-2.0.jar!/applicationContext-transactional-service.xml]
[2017-03-20 12:17:33,551] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory [main] Overriding bean definition for bean 'loginService': replacing [Generic bean: class [ma.archostechnology.softwork.service.login.LoginService]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/STG/Desktop/woork/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/perWeb/WEB-INF/lib/perService-2.0.jar!/applicationContext-simple-service.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/STG/Desktop/woork/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/perWeb/WEB-INF/lib/perService-2.0.jar!/applicationContext-transactional-service.xml]]
[2017-03-20 12:17:33,565] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader [main] Loading XML bean definitions from file [C:\Users\STG\Desktop\woork\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\perWeb\WEB-INF\classes\applicationContext-acegi-security.xml]
[2017-03-20 12:17:33,867] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor [main] JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
[2017-03-20 12:17:33,929] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory [main] Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3dd6db4a: defining beans [dataSourcePER,sessionFactoryPER,transactionManagerPER,userDAO,civiliteDAO,professionDAO,fluxDAO,partenaireDAO,familleDAO,modePenaliteDAO,produitDAO,typeFluxDAO,profilDAO,banqueDAO,agenceDAO,compteDAO,intermediaireDAO,droitDAO,autorityDAO,souscriptionDAO,souscriptionAdcDAO,avenantDAO,souscripteurDAO,assureDAO,actionDAO,tauxDAO,prelevementDAO,versementDAO,rachatTotalDAO,rachatPartielDAO,exerciceDAO,tarifDecesOptionnelleDAO,typeAvenantDAO,SequenceFluxDAO,reserveMathematiqueDAO,situationDAO,situationAvanceDAO,valeurTauxDAO,impayeDAO,ordreVirementDAO,adresseDAO,cotisationPeriodiqueDAO,tauxDecesObligatoireDAO,decesOptionnelleDAO,epargneDAO,souscriptionHistoriqueDAO,prestationDAO,beneficiaireDAO,genericDAO,evenementDAO,liquidationDAO,natureLiquidationDAO,motifDepartDAO,reservePatronaleServiceDAO,avanceDAO,remboursementAvanceDAO,sinistreDAO,pieceJointeDAO,avanceRevaloriseDAO,parametreDAO,trancheDAO,queryBuilderFactoryID,reserveMathematiqueTmpDAO,simulationDAO,baremAxRenteDao,renteDAO,prestationAnnulerDAO,historiqueAvanceDAO,historiqueCotisationDAO,pieceJustificativeDAO,DossierSinistreDAO,beneficiaireSinistreDAO,reglementPartielSinistreDAO,coeff_ReversionDAO,conjointDAO,benefNantissementDAO,appCacheManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,avenantService,fluxService,preProcessorParsing,agenceService,banqueService,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,inputFileBatchDispatcher,perManagerBatch,perManagerCronTrigger,situationAvanceBatch,situationAvanceCronTrigger,mettreAjourProvisionBatch,mettreAjourProvisionCronTrigger,reglementFichierBatch,reglementFichierCronTrigger,generationImpayesBatch,generationImpayesCronTrigger,impayesBatch,impayesCronTrigger,avenantBatch,avenantCronTrigger,AvanceToRachatPartielBatch,AvanceToRachatPartielCronTrigger,org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0,reglementChequeFichierBatch,reglementChequeFichierCronTrigger,simulationBatch,simulationBatchCronTrigger,avanceConvertiFichierBatch,avanceConvertiFichierCronTrigger,perController,userServiceImpl,loginServiceImpl,loginService,profilServiceImpl,defaultParseurProcessor,abstractTemplateParsingService,souscriptionParseurEducationServiceImp,souscriptionParseurServiceImp,souscriptionApportInParseurServiceImp,primeAssuranceValidator,prelevementValidator,versementValidator,versementexceptionnelParseurServiceImp,transfertParseurServiceImp,avenantParseurServiceImp,contratServiceImpl,souscriptionEducationService,souscriptionService,quittanceService,civiliteService,professionService,produitService,intermediaireService,partenaireService,versemenetExceptionnelService,tarifDecesOptionnelleService,fluxCritereService,fluxEmisService,parametrageService,prelevementService,prelevementParseurPrelevementImp,rachatPartielService,rachatPartielParseurServiceImp,rachatTotalService,rachatTotalParseurServiceImp,calculMathematiqueService,informationFluxFactory,parseurServiceFacade,AcquitementService,SequenceFluxService,RachatPartielQuittanceService,rachatTotalQuittanceService,liquidationQuittanceService,avanceQuittanceService,sinistreQuittanceService,ReglementQuittanceService,reglementChequeQuittanceService,SituationService,impayeService,simulationService,tauxService,traitementAvenantAbstract,changementAdresseAvenant,changementBeneficiaresAvenant,changementCapitalAssureGarantieOptionnelleAvenant,changementCotisationRetraiteAvenant,changementDateEcheanceAvenant,changementDatePrelevementAvenant,changementGarantieOptionnelleAvenant,changementNumCompteBancaireAvenant,changementOptionFiscaleAvenant,changementOptionNantissementAvenant,changementPeriodiciteAvenant,changementPeriodiciteAutomatiqueAvenant,changementCapitalAssureGarantieOptionnelleMntCotAutoAvenant,resiliationSouscriptionAvenant,changementEnfantBeneficiaire,changementFicheSignaletiqueSouscripteurAvenant,changementFicheSignaletiqueAssureAvenant,traitementAvenantFactory,prestationReglementServiceImp,prestationTraitementServiceImp,reportingRechercheService,provisionMathematiqueReportingService,releveSituationReportingService,commonService,natureLiquidationService,reservePatronaleService,motifDepartService,liquidationService,liquidationParseurServiceImp,avanceService,avanceParseurServiceImp,sinistreService,sinistreParseurServiceImp,pieceJointeService,moveFileHelper,userService,profilService,contratService,souscriptionParseurEducationService,souscriptionParseurService,souscriptionApportInParseurService,versementexceptionnelParseurService,transfertParseurService,avenantParseurService,prelevementParseurService,rachatPartielParseurService,rachatTotalParseurService,prestationTraitementService,prestationReglementService,souscriptionServiceTrx,quittanceServiceTrx,commonServiceTrx,liquidationParseurService,avanceParseurService,sinistreParseurService,filterChainProxy,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,logoutFilter,authenticationProcessingFilter,securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,rememberMeProcessingFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor,rememberMeServices,authenticationManager,daoAuthenticationProvider,sessionExpirationFilter,saltSource,passwordEncoder,loggerListener,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
[2017-03-20 12:17:33,941] INFO  com.mchange.v2.log.MLog [main] MLog clients using log4j logging.
[2017-03-20 12:17:34,006] INFO  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry [main] Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.2 [built 21-May-2007 15:04:56; debug? true; trace: 10]
[2017-03-20 12:17:34,645] INFO  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource [main] Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1bqoqsc9m1tdupsb1b7jp4y|4c9fc2e7, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1bqoqsc9m1tdupsb1b7jp4y|4c9fc2e7, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 3000, initialPoolSize -> 2, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:sqlserver://172.16.17.237;databaseName=PerNew, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 1800, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 500, maxStatements -> 500, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 2, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
[2017-03-20 12:17:36,676] INFO  net.sf.ehcache.util.UpdateChecker [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@a8a8c0a] New update(s) found: 2.4.7 [http://www.terracotta.org/confluence/display/release/Release+Notes+Ehcache+Core+2.4]. Please check http://ehcache.org for the latest version.
[2017-03-20 12:17:39,978] INFO  org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager [main] Using DataSource [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1bqoqsc9m1tdupsb1b7jp4y|4c9fc2e7, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1bqoqsc9m1tdupsb1b7jp4y|4c9fc2e7, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 3000, initialPoolSize -> 2, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:sqlserver://172.16.17.237;databaseName=PerNew, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 1800, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 500, maxStatements -> 500, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 2, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
```

And that's what i've found in the logs

```
mars 21, 2017 11:05:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
mars 21, 2017 11:05:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

And here is what i got in the thread dump

```
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode):

"org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache.data" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000f03e800 nid=0x1294 waiting on condition [0x0000000012c3e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c7706498> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1090)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache.data" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000c91f800 nid=0x182c waiting on condition [0x00000000129df000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c7710fd0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1090)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I changed the tomcat time out to 5 min but still it doesn't work. and i deleted the old server and add a new one but i got the same problem. I've even tried a new server tomcat 7, and i started tomcat from command lines but it doesn't work tomcat just hang there

I don't know what's wrong, Any ideas on how to fix this?

Edit___________________________________________________

Here is what i got when i enabled spring debugging

```
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,872] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'class' of type [java.lang.Class]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,872] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'currentSession' of type [org.hibernate.Session]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,872] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata [localhost-startStop-1] Processing injected method of bean 'userDAO': AutowiredFieldElement for org.hibernate.SessionFactory ma.archostechnology.softwork.dao.impl.GenericDAO.sessionFactory
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory [localhost-startStop-1] Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'loginService'
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory [localhost-startStop-1] Creating instance of bean 'loginService'
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory [localhost-startStop-1] Eagerly caching bean 'loginService' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Getting BeanInfo for class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Caching PropertyDescriptors for class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'advisorAdapterRegistry' of type [org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AdvisorAdapterRegistry]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'beanClassLoader' of type [java.lang.ClassLoader]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'beanFactory' of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'class' of type [java.lang.Class]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'exposeProxy' of type [boolean]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'frozen' of type [boolean]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'object' of type [java.lang.Object]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'objectType' of type [java.lang.Class]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'opaque' of type [boolean]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'optimize' of type [boolean]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'pointcut' of type [org.springframework.aop.Pointcut]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'postInterceptors' of type [[Ljava.lang.Object;]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'preInterceptors' of type [[Ljava.lang.Object;]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'proxyClassLoader' of type [java.lang.ClassLoader]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'proxyInterfaces' of type [[Ljava.lang.Class;]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'proxyTargetClass' of type [boolean]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'singleton' of type [boolean]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'target' of type [java.lang.Object]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'transactionAttributeSource' of type [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSource]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'transactionAttributes' of type [java.util.Properties]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'transactionManager' of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory [localhost-startStop-1] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManagerPER'
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory [localhost-startStop-1] Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'loginServiceImpl'
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory [localhost-startStop-1] Creating instance of bean 'loginServiceImpl'
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory [localhost-startStop-1] Eagerly caching bean 'loginServiceImpl' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,887] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Getting BeanInfo for class [ma.archostechnology.softwork.service.login.LoginService]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,903] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Caching PropertyDescriptors for class [ma.archostechnology.softwork.service.login.LoginService]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,903] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'class' of type [java.lang.Class]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,903] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'dao' of type [ma.archostechnology.softwork.dao.IGenericDAO]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,903] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults [localhost-startStop-1] Found bean property 'user' of type [ma.archostechnology.softwork.dao.mappings.Utilisateur]
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,903] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory [localhost-startStop-1] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,903] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory [localhost-startStop-1] Returning eagerly cached instance of singleton bean 'userDAO' that is not fully initialized yet - a consequence of a circular reference
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,903] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils [localhost-startStop-1] No property editor [ma.archostechnology.softwork.dao.IGenericDAOEditor] found for type ma.archostechnology.softwork.dao.IGenericDAO according to 'Editor' suffix convention
[2017-03-21 14:33:40,903] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory [localhost-startStop-1] Ignoring bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/Programmes/apache-tomcat-7.0.33/webapps/perWeb/WEB-INF/lib/perService-2.0.jar!/applicationContext-transactional-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginServiceImpl' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/Programmes/apache-tomcat-7.0.33/webapps/perWeb/WEB-INF/lib/perService-2.0.jar!/applicationContext-simple-service.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'ma.archostechnology.softwork.dao.impl.GenericDAO' to required type 'ma.archostechnology.softwork.dao.IGenericDAO' for property 'dao'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [ma.archostechnology.softwork.dao.impl.GenericDAO] to required type [ma.archostechnology.softwork.dao.IGenericDAO] for property 'dao': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Comment: No there isn't a database lock

Comment: Enable more detailed logging for the Spring framework, i.e. logger name="org.springframework" level="trace". I see you have many Spring beans, but I don't see from the log file what is initialized and what is not.

Comment: Also make sure you check in all the log files, e.g. catalina.log, catalina.out, access.log etc. in addition to your application log. Usually it hangs since there is a clear initialization error, just spot it.

Comment: check and share your class which implements ServletContextListener

Comment: I didn't find such class. Actualy it's not my project i'm just working on migrating it to Spring 3.2.3 and hibernate 4. It used to work just fine with spring 2.5.5 and hibernate 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Last Line in Log :

there is no @Id annotation above the primary field in target

[2017-03-21 14:33:40,903] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory [localhost-startStop-1] Ignoring bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/Programmes/apache-tomcat-7.0.33/webapps/perWeb/WEB-INF/lib/perService-2.0.jar!/applicationContext-transactional-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginServiceImpl' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/Programmes/apache-tomcat-7.0.33/webapps/perWeb/WEB-INF/lib/perService-2.0.jar!/applicationContext-simple-service.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'ma.archostechnology.softwork.dao.impl.GenericDAO' to required type 'ma.archostechnology.softwork.dao.IGenericDAO' for property 'dao'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [ma.archostechnology.softwork.dao.impl.GenericDAO] to required type [ma.archostechnology.softwork.dao.IGenericDAO] for property 'dao': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Double click on Server

Increase timeout to 120 seconds

Comment: Double-click on Server. There is option to start the server in seconds

Comment: Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds

Comment: Press Ctrl+S, to save the change and restart the server

Comment: yeah i even increased it to 5 min but tomcat doesn't proceed

Comment: There is a problem with the title in the question. People that will get this default message in eclipse will be looking for answers like this.

Comment: there is no @Id annotation above the primary field in target or loginServiceImpl

Comment: thanks for your answer but i already have the  annotation 
 @Id GeneratedValue
 public Integer getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(Integer id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

Comment: send me the source code on my personal mail id to check if i can help